# Generate XML files for testing from XSD schema

Tags: xml, testing, xsd, xml-validation, xml-generation

I have a complex collection of XSD schema that I have already used to validate some existing XML examples, using Python lxml.  Now I'm trying to generate additional XML examples from the existing XSD schema. These new XML examples will be used for future testing.  The examples need to be fully populated XML documents (for testing).

It would be impractical to hand generate the number of testing XMLs.  Are there any tools that can help me do this? How would I go about generating a bunch of example XML (they must still validate against the XSD)?  I need something that can generate a large number of unique xml files.

I'm currently working on Linux and would prefer a solution that is compatible.

Answer (score 0):

The XML editor oXygen has an tool to generate instances from a schema document as an option on its Tools menu; I expect some other XML IDEs do, too.